# Ordering of parameters in Swagger-ui

Tags: python, flask, swagger-ui, flask-restplus

I'm using Flask and Flask-restplus to build an API with a swagger UI.
Routes seem to be displayed in alphabetical order, but as for parameters of these routes, they seem to be displayed in a completely random order that changes every time I re-build my project.

I have searched thoroughly for a way to set the order in which parameters appear on the UI, but I have not found anything at all (I expected that many people would have had the same question).

Is there no way to set the ordering of parameters?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the operationsSorter and write a custom sort function. Here's an example:

```
// dist/index.html

const ui = SwaggerUIBundle({
url: "http://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json",
...

operationsSorter: (a, b) => {

        var methodsOrder = ["get", "post", "put", "delete", "patch", "options", "trace"];

        var result = methodsOrder.indexOf( a.get("method") ) - methodsOrder.indexOf( b.get("method") );
      // Or if you want to sort the methods alphabetically (delete, get, head, 
      options, 
      ...):
     // var result = a.get("method").localeCompare(b.get("method"));

      if (result === 0) {
       result = a.get("path").localeCompare(b.get("path"));
      }

   return result;
  }
})
```

Comment: I want to sort the parameters of the get/post/etc., not the get/post/etc. themselves

Comment: Provide CLI option sortParamsByRequiredFlag to optionally sort method arguments based on required/optional.

Comment: you can pass sortParamsByRequiredFlag in a config file (json) to disable sorting the method argument.